# What is the correct way to swap elements in multidiamensional arrays in loops?

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array, swap

I have a piece of code that runs through a table and with a propability of "pxover", swaps some elements in it. What elements should swap, are found with a propability of 0.5. The algorithm does the swap when two elements are found. The evaluation_table formation is this:

```
[[(x11,y11),(x12,y12), ... (x1el,y1el)],[(x21,y21),(x22,y22), ...,
  (x2el,y2el)], ... ,[(xpop1,ypop1),(xpop2,ypop2), ..., (xpopel,ypopel)]]
```

The code is below:

```
def crossover(evaluation_table, pop, no_of_elements, pxover):
    xover_positions = []
    chosen_count = 0
    for i in range(pop):
        x = uniform(0,1)
        if x<=pxover:
            chosen_count = chosen_count + 1
            if chosen_count % 2 == 0:
                for element in range(no_of_elements):
                    element_swap_prop = uniform(0, 1)
                    if element_swap_prop <= 0.5:
                        evaluation_table[i][element], evaluation_table[j][element] = evaluation_table[j][element], evaluation_table[i][element]
            else:
                j = i
        xover_positions.append(evaluation_table[i])
```

However, the code does not swap all the elements correctly. Some elements are swapped correctly while some other are swapped with the right index "el" but wrong index "pop".

For example (x11,y11) should swap with (x31,y31) but only the first goes in the place of the second while in the place of the first goes (xk1,xk2) with k a number larger than 3.

I did some research and applied this answer:

[Can't swap the elements in a list, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787442/cant-swap-the-elements-in-a-list-python)

but the same issue persisted.

Also, some elements that shouldn't change values at all, get elements from random positions!

**Edit**: I run my code into a debugger and figured out that in the order of swap:

```
 evaluation_table[i][element], evaluation_table[j][element] = evaluation_table[j][element], evaluation_table[i][element]
```

it swap not only the contents of i and j but also those of one or two more randomly randomly. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, it had to do with references between table cells. The funny thing is that when i deepcopied the table, the same issue persisted. What I did to fix this, was to deepcopy eace row separetly. So, I post the solution here:

```
xover_positions = []
for i in range(pop):
    xover_positions.append(deepcopy(evaluation_table[i]))
```

and then used the "xover_positions" table for the swaps. It seems like there where relationships between the rows of the table from a previous function, so this settles it.